# send email via Intent with specified from address

Tags: android, email, android-intent

I know we can trigger an `Intent.ACTION_SEND` intent to send email. But according to the official api docs, we can't specify "from address" sending an email(EXTRA_EMAIL->to address). So is it possible to specify the from address? if possible, then how?

Thanks in advance.~bow

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883199/using-android-intent-action-send-for-sending-mail

Comment: hi, sorry for my confusing problem description. What I want to do is specifying the sender address. Intent seems only support recipient address(put EXTRA_EMAIL), not support specifying sender address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was wonder why you need *from address filed* in your email, because you had configured e-mail settings in your device.

For Instance:

I had configured my gmail account in my android device[abc@gmail.com], so if i send email using Intents to xyz@yahoo.com , the receiving user receives my mail with outlined my gmail id which i had configured in my device i.e., abc@gmail.com.

Refer My Blog for any info regarding email using Intents , i had gave a detailed explanation

http://sankarganesh-info-exchange.blogspot.com/p/sending-e-mails-in-android-using-intent.html

Or still you need from address, you can send Email without using Intents

Refer this article http://www.jondev.net/articles/Sending_Emails_without_User_Intervention_(no_Intents)_in_Android
Here they are clearly explained abt sending emails without using Intents