# Send an email while showing only email programs

Tags: android

I have multiple posts about sending an email and even in the Android documentations. IT does not seem to work. I want to basically to allow the user to choose their email programs to send an email. Here is the code

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
                emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
                emailIntent.setType("*/*");
                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"xyz@gmail.com"});
                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "msg");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
```

However it does nothing (ie no activity)

What is it that I am doing wrong? If I use Action.Send then it display all social medial platforms including facebook and whatsapp ..etc

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is taken from [Adroid developers site](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common) and combining with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883199/using-android-intent-action-send-for-sending-email):

```
public void composeEmail(String[] addresses, String subject, String msessage) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("application/octet-stream");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, addresses);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Note I made a few changes to match the case of the question.

Comment: It is showing other non email programs such as whatsapp, bluetooth, slack ..etc

Comment: Based on the same question, ste type to: application/octet-stream. I'll change it in the answer. Though I am not sure if it will work correclty as EXTRA_STREAM is no being set.