# Unable to attach files to Gmail from cache directory Android 12

Tags: android, pdf, gmail, android-12, android-api-31

I almost found many similar links - and none helped

1. Gmail is not allowing me to get file from /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/myapppackage/cache/..pdf tried both manually using Gmail and programmatically
2. Able to attach if the same file is downloaded to /storage/emulated/0/download/..pdf

CODE -

```
protected void sendEmail(Context ctx, String filePath){
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    Uri uri = Uri.fromfile(new File(filePath)));
    emailIntent.setType("application/pdf");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "PDF"));
    ctx.startActivity(emailIntent);
}
```

file_provder.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <cache-path name="cache" path="/" />
    <files-path name="files" path="/" />
</paths>
```

Tried the following link which almost seems like perfect but doesn't work for me - [Attaching cache file to GMail through FileProvider and Intent not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65463541/attaching-cache-file-to-gmail-through-fileprovider-and-intent-not-working)

Comment: It makes no sense to post file_provider.xlm if you do not use it. Use FileProvider to get an uri and not Uri.fromFile().

Comment: Adapt your code please and start showing wich value is assigned to `filePath`.

Comment: `Gmail is not allowing me` If you use FileProvider, and you should, then Gmail sees an uri. It cannot see such a path to begin with. It has no idea where the file comes from. And Gmail does not need any access permission if you use FileProvider.

Comment: Thank you for the advice @blackapps, it worked after getting the url from fileprovider

Answer (score 0):

This might help someone in the future, instead of getting uri directly from file path i just used file provider to get the uri which returns content://path

```
protected void sendEmail(Context ctx, String filePath){
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(ctx, ctx.getPackageName, (new File(filepath)));
    emailIntent.setType("application/pdf");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "PDF"));
    ctx.startActivity(emailIntent);
}
```