# EXTRA_EMAIL in SEND_TO Intent does not set the recipient value

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-intent

I have this simple SENT_TO intent which followed the basic syntax of android intent.

```
 val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO).apply {
        data = Uri.parse("mailto:")
        putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, arrayOf("to1","to2"))
        putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject")
        putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "text")
    }
```

However, whenever the activity launch, the `EXTRA_EMAIL` never pass the value to the recipient. Could someone point me the problem here? (I work with Gmail app)

[image]

Comment: Since `EXTRA_EMAIL` is undocumented for use with `ACTION_SENDTO`, there is no requirement for an email client to use that extra. You might try putting them in the `mailto:` `Uri` itself.

Comment: @CommonsWare now that I wrote like this: `val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("mailto:ihavenoname@gmail.com")).apply {
            putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject")
            putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "text")
        }`, the email passed, but subject and text now did not pass.

Comment: What seems to be the problem here? The Intent limits its putExtra?

Comment: You can try putting the subject and body [in the `mailto:` `Uri` itself](https://www.simplilearn.com/tutorials/html-tutorial/html-mailto), as you did with the address. "What seems to be the problem here?" -- you are attempting to send an email through any one of many possible email apps using `ACTION_SENDTO`. [`ACTION_SENDTO` is not documented to accept any extras](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_SENDTO). So, an email app's developers are well within their rights to not bother paying attention to your extras.

Comment: @CommonsWare you are a legend. I've been fixing this dude for days. I give you 10 Big Thumbs Up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those extras are documented for `ACTION_SEND`, not `ACTION_SENDTO`. So, already, you're in trouble, as there is nothing requiring an email app developer to pay attention to them.

Beyond that, extras are optional bits of data. Email apps can ignore them, even when they are documented.

Some email clients will pay attention to those extras with `ACTION_SENDTO`. I recently found that the now-current version of Gmail does (though I only tested with a single email address, not the two in your question). However, that's not guaranteed across all Gmail versions, let alone across all email apps.

An alternative approach for `ACTION_SENDTO` with a `mailto:` `Uri` is to put the address(es), subject, and body in [the `mailto:` itself](https://www.simplilearn.com/tutorials/html-tutorial/html-mailto). However, that too is not guaranteed to work.

What's *supposed* to work is [`ACTION_SEND`, your extras, an a `mailto` selector](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42856167/115145). That recently started failing to find Gmail, causing me to flip a table (virtually). So, now, I'm using that selector approach, and code reminiscent of your question as a fallback if no activities match the selector `Intent`.