# How to send an email in android 2.2?

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to send an email with android 2.2. First I made an intent chooser with an ACTION_SEND to select which to use  :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, Resources.getString("EmailInvitationSubject", getBaseContext()));
String body = Resources.getString("EmailInvitationBody", getBaseContext()) + Local.User.FirstName;
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Invite friends"));
```

But in that case, the selector show 'Bluetooth, Messaging, Google+, Gmail'. I want to show ONLY Gmail or other email app.

I saw in the sdk docs there's a new CATEGORY_APP_EMAIL to use but it's only available in the API level 15. I have to keep API level 8. Is there a way to do that ?

By the way, I'll want to do it for messaging too so that in the end I can have 2 buttons: one for email and one for messaging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code will shows only the email clients,

```
   Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"youremail@yahoo.com"});          
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "message");
    email.setType("message/rfc822");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client :"));
```

Comment: is that normal to call setType() twice ?

Comment: if you need more clarification refer this site http://www.mkyong.com/android/how-to-send-email-in-android/

Comment: any idea of which type I have to set to get messaging apps ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11311/discussion-between-jafar-and-aerrow)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to checkout following (to get what you are looking at the end, i.e. "....By the way, I'll want to do it for messaging too so that in the end I can have 2 buttons: "):
http://www.jondev.net/articles/Sending_Emails_without_User_Intervention_%28no_Intents%29_in_Android

or also you could checkout:
[Android email chooser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3979226/android-email-chooser)

Kind regards,
Bo

Comment: Thanks but I would like to keep the user using gmail or his own email app so that he can choose the recipients from his contact list or modify the message etc...