# Intent for viewing incoming email messages/opening email app

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm writing an android app that requires the user to confirm their subscription by clicking a link received by email. For this I would like to create a shortcut to open the preferred email-application. The following code crashes my Gmail app:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setType("message/rfc822");
startActivity(intent);
```

Would there be another solution to solve this?

Comment: do you want to open only gmail in particular?

Comment: Just chooser behaviour. If > 1 clients can handle email, then a chooser should pop-up, otherwise just open the installed app.

Comment: ok. Are you sending any attachments as well? I have a solution but that is not working for attachments

Comment: I dont want to send. I want to open the email app as I just need to click on a link.

Comment: ok.. posting an answer for your requirement. try it.

Answer (score 1):

Correcting your code:
message/rfc822 as the MIME type- It is not indicating -- only show email clients -- it indicates --show anything that supports message/rfc822 data. That could include some application that are not email clients.

According to Android [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Email). If you want to ensure that your intent is handled only by an email app (and not other text messaging or social apps), then use the ACTION_SENDTO action and include the "mailto:" data scheme. For example:

```
    public void composeEmail(String[] addresses, String subject) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, addresses);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: This starts a message composer... I need to show the inbound email list.

Comment: for me it was working a few years ago. Might be some changes in recent version. Try above code in combination with this SO answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/3982785/3142342

Answer (score 0):

Use this structure to create chooser for apps that can perform email sending.

```
        Intent mIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        mIntent.setType("text/html");
        mIntent.putExtra(...); // if you need extra just add it here
        mIntent = Intent.createChooser(mIntent, "Select Email Application...");
        startActivity(mIntent);
```